# JSF "Remember me" option

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, session-timeout

In other languages when a user logs in you can set the expire date of a cookie really far from today's and you can achieve this. How can I implement this in JSF2? I have a jsf sessionscoped bean but how can I maintain this session for a long time?.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/java-ee-6-how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-appli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add cookies with JSF as well:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext.addResponseCookie(..)
```

in the parameters map you can set the expiration date - see [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#addResponseCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) for all parameteres

Comment: Yes but what I need to do is set the SessionScoped bean to last for a long time, not expire when the user closes his browser

Comment: @arg: This is not the right approach. When the session bean get created, it should just check the presence of the long-living cookie you've created before and then preinitialize the data associated with it.

Comment: @BalusC I know it's a outdated comment but how would you do the login with the info you have in the cookie ? I'm actually looking at jaspic at the moment to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is tagged JSF but I recommend you look into [Spring's Solution to the Remember Me problem.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html)