# Glassfish Security - jdbcRealm: How to implement "remember-me"

Tags: security, java-ee-6, remember-me, jdbcrealm, jacc

I'm using jdbcRealm with Glassfish V3 and Java EE 6 and I want to implement a cookie based "Remember-Me".

But, it seems that I cannot set a filter before the JACC security checking. Any Ideas?

Comment: There is a lengthy and good answer on your question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/java-ee-6-how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-appli

Comment: That is a good discussion. I quite like both responses it has but Mihai Claudiu Toader's answer is very insightful and I quite like it. As an added comment, the assumption here is that you are asking about 'remember me' in terms of Java Server Faces. I don't really know if EJBs are able to provide remember me functionality.