# Keep me logged in JSF after closing the browser

Tags: jsf-2, session-state

I have a Session bean with many params (user, logged, password... etc)...
How can i save only this bean for when a user accesses the web again in a other browser he can keep logged?

¿Is posible to save only some variables from entire bean?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are referring to Remember Me functionality for your application. If so refer to this question [stay logged in when user login to the web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/java-ee-6-how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-appli)

Comment: Yes, you have reason. Thanks!