# Java User Management Security Implementation

Tags: java, security, session, cookies

I am implementing a user login system and just want to run my security concerns by the community.

I plan on using Java's PBKDF2 to encrypt and store the users password/salt in the database upon the creation of the user account. Of course everything will be done over HTTPS. The resource I used contains actual source code documenting how to implement this functionality and i'll include that link at the end of the question.

Onto the "remember me" functionality. Is the proper way to implement this to:

1. Generate a UUID Session key upon login, store key in database, store key client side in cookie.
2. When a new session is created, get the key from the cookie, compare to database, create a new key and restore it client side.

Is there any security vulnerability here? I know a lot of resources suggest also storing the users ip address along side the session key and invalidating the key if the ip does not match. Doesn't the ip change quite often if the user is coming from a mobile network? Even on wifi, these days it seems most applications are not using ip verifcation? Say your dynamic ip changes, an application like Gmail doesn't log you out does it?

Resources:

Storing secure passwords in Java: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html

Implementing "stay logged in" in Java: [How to implement "Stay Logged In" when user login in to the web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/java-ee-6-how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-appli)

Comment: Spring security supports all this and much more - check it out, don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: I cannot use Spring in my application. It seems Java has most of this stuff baked in. Not necessarily reinventing the wheel?