# Save user preferences on client-side

Tags: java, jsf

What is the best way of saving preferences on client side (eg. language choice) for a JSF WebApp?  I would like the data to persist the closing of the browser.  Per requirement I can't use the browser locale to detect the preferred language.

I was hoping for something like a BrowserScoped bean.  Should I try using a CustomScoped bean (I've never used them before) or should I use plain old JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: To save these kind of preferences you must use cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for long living Cookies to me.

You should take a look at  `ExternalContext.addResponseCookie()` to store your cookie and `HttpServletRequest.getCookies()` to retrieve it.
Although it's not the same use case as yours I would like to refer you to [this BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/java-ee-6-how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-appli/5083809#5083809) if you want grant your cookies a long life.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend an approach involving [JavaScript DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). You can tie it to a session if necessary. It boils down to a map of properties at its core, that is accessible from your app's domain.