# Remembering user authentication

Tags: authentication, cookies, browser, browser-cache

After connecting to *udemy course* or *gmail inbox* through my login, browser never again asks for user authentication.

Need to delete browser history, to re-enter user authentication on both chrome & firefox.

---

What is the cache mechanism of a browser to retrieve & maintain such user information persistently, on hard disk? Is server involved in this cache mechanism?

Comment: I would go for cookies

Comment: @jeprubio Is cookie creation & maintenance has nothing to do with back end server?

Comment: Is usually the way browsers remember the user is logged in. Remove the cookies and you'll see you are not logged in anymore.

Comment: @jeprubio wiki says, *is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored on the user's computer by the user's web browser while the user is browsing* So, Is cookie created by server and sent to client browser?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Improved Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice).

And also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website).

You basically need cookies to remember that the user has logged in. But never save things like the username and password, just a token.

Comment: To do it with java I would follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-application I've read it and all seems correct.