# Using Cookies in JSF Application to remember login credentials

Tags: jsf, cookies, omnifaces

I want to store username and password as cookies and allow user to login to a JSF application without entering then on next login.

I have tired OmniFaces to achieve that task. Still the user has to enter the details every-time. The cookies seems not to be stored nor retrieved properly.

How to achieve this functionality in JSF, with or without using OmniFaces?

JSF Controller

```
package com.beans;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;

@Named(value = "webUserController")
@SessionScoped
public class WebUserController implements Serializable {

    String username;
    String password;
    boolean logged = false;

    public WebUserController() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        username = Faces.getRequestCookie("username");
        password = Faces.getRequestCookie("password");
        logged = canLog();

    }

    public void loginAction(){
        if(canLog()){
            logged = true;
            Faces.addResponseCookie("username", username, -1);
            Faces.addResponseCookie("password", password, -1);
        }else{
            logged = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean canLog(){
        if(username==null||password==null){
           return false;
        }
        if(username.equals("b") && password.equals("b")){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isLogged() {
        return logged;
    }

    public void setLogged(boolean logged) {
       this.logged = logged;
    }

}
```

This is the index.xhtml file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form >
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{webUserController.logged}" >
            <h1>You are logged</h1>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!webUserController.logged}" >
            <h1>Please login</h1>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
                Username
                <h:inputText value="#{webUserController.username}" ></h:inputText>

                Password
                <h:inputText value="#{webUserController.password}" ></h:inputText>

                <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{webUserController.loginAction()}" ></h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: This has already been asked and answered by BalusC.  Here is the right way to do what you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-application

Comment: It is when we use Servalets. I have no knowledge on that. We use JSF pages and CDI.

Comment: Servlets are available in a JSF/CDI app.  The core of JSF is Faces"servlet".  Also you might really want to read this article on what to do an NOT to do when trying to implement what you want. https://www.troyhunt.com/how-to-build-and-how-not-to-build/ This has serious security implications using cookies.

Comment: Setting/getting a password from a cookie is bad practice. Advice: don't develop your own AAA mechanism, use picketlink, shiro or whatever