# I'm using form-based security for my Java EE project and it takes back me to login page after i exit the browser without logout

Tags: authentication, jsf-2

I'm new to java web security. I've done a project that authenticates and authorizes very well using JSF form-based authentication. But the problem is that when i close the browser without logging out and reopen the browser and try to access the project it brings the login page and i can not login. To login i've to deploy the project again. I'm not trying to add the 'Remember Me' feature. Can you guys help me on what I've to do to stay logged in even when i close and reopen the browser and access the project without being asked to login again unless i logged out intentionally.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement "Stay Logged In" when user login in to the web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082846/how-to-implement-stay-logged-in-when-user-login-in-to-the-web-application)

Comment: No. I'm no trying to add the 'Remember me' feature. The problem I'm facing now is once i logged in and close without logout, reopen the browser, and try to access my project it does not  log me in automatically. It takes me to the login page and the user name/email of the the account that i previously logged in with stays at the user name/email field and i cannot login again. To logon i have redeploy the project. I'm merely trying to avoid this problem?

Comment: You asked for advice. The other question referenced explains a general approach on how to implement "remember me" functionality. Without more information it's impossible to know whats wrong in your application specifically. The behavior you are describing could be caused by a number of things.