# Container Managed Security with Remember Me option

Tags: jsf-2, security

I have container managed security enabled using a JDBC realm in glassfish.

Now I wanted to add Remember Me option capability so that user is not required to login everytime.

I haved searched the forum and found this two links ["remember me" functionality with jsf 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321309/remember-me-functionality-with-jsf-2-0)
and [JSF "Remember me" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981246/jsf-remember-me-option) but I still can't understand how to implement remember me.

Does anybody have an advise how to do this?

I know Spring has solution for this but I am not using Spring option and I am using the following stack
in building my web project

JSF2/EJB/JPA2/Glassfish/Primefaces

Comment: Your first link has in the question comment a link to other question with a pretty detailed answer. Have you noticed it? If so, what exactly is unclear to you then?

Comment: Hi BalusC, I failed to notice your comment in the first link.  The question there maps to a Servlet but my question refers to a JSF 2 application.  I am having trouble mapping these two technologies.  In effect can you discuss if how can this be done in a JSF application?

Comment: Hi BalusC, just to add.  I am not using programmmatic login in JSF2 but relies solely on using
the Glassfish container managed security.  I am not sure where to add the cookie.  Also, I got confused with the 
purpose of the filter in your post, do I really have to set this up when using JSF? Except for the index.jsp, all of my pages uses
the faces-servlet for dispatching.  Sorry, I am just too confused.  Thanks